# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='onNotificationPosted' signature='()V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, c#, android, unity3d, плагин

у меня есть рабочее java приложение которое регистрирует приходящие уведомления на моем смартфоне, и показывает их у меня в приложении... Теперь мне нужно как-то показать эти уведомления у меня в unity приложении... Я сделал плагин, и вот мой java код(взят из рабочего андроид приложения, поэтому естественно без передачи полученных данных в Main Activity):

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public class ReceiveIncomingNotifications extends NotificationListenerService {
    Context context;
    public String title;
    public String text;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override

    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker ="";
        if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) {
            ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        }
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        title = extras.getString("android.title");
        text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
        int id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
        Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;

        if(id != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            id.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        }

    }
}
```

вот мой c# код, где я вызываю метод `onNotificationPosted` , присваиваю unity переменным содержимое java переменных, и затем уже через текст вывожу содержимое юнити переменных мне на экран:

```
public class ReceiveIncomingNotifications : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Title;
    public string Text;
    public TextMeshProUGUI TextForTitle;
    public TextMeshProUGUI TextForBody;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        var plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.alexcompany.librarythatreceiveincomingnotificationsandpasstounity.ReceiveIncomingNotifications");
        plugin.Call("onNotificationPosted");
        Title = plugin.Get<string>("title");
        Text = plugin.Get<string>("text");
        TextForTitle.text = Title;
        TextForBody.text = Text;
    }
}
```

при запуске моего приложения в `logcat` получаю ошибку:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='onNotificationPosted' signature='()V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
```

может ли это быть связано с тем что в java коде мой метод принимает аргумент, а в c# я просто пишу название этого метода? или может мне стоит создать `interface` в android-studio и `callback` в unity? При создании плагина я в проекте android studio создал `android library`, и затем получил ...-aar.release, который и вложил в `Assets->Plugins->Android` Пожалуйста, может кто-то знает что это за ошибка? Заранее спасибо!

UPD.: я так подумал, насчет C#... в void Update вызывать метод который должен срабатывать тогда когда уведомление приходит как-то странно... Ну а как тогда?

Comment: А тогда наоборот - когда уведомление пришло, из java-кода нужно вызвать шарп код и передать ему это событие с нужными данными.

Comment: Здравствуйте=), то есть  код в моем плагине может работать даже если я к нему не обращаюсь из C#? и получается когда уведомление приходит, и в моих Java переменных появляется содержимое я из java кода вызываю c# метод, в котором и присваиваю содержимое java переменных C# переменным?

Comment: или это можно сделать как здесь?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652202/reading-sms-from-inbox-in-unity-android-and-ios-deployment

Comment: Зайди в Publishing Settings, которые находятся в Player Settings и посмотри, не стоят ли галочки в секции Minify. Лично я сам долго сидел с такой проблемой и это решение помогло

Comment: Здравствуйте Methorn! Помню Вы писали об этом под одним из предыдущих моих вопросов) Галочки убраны, спасибо! ```=) ```

Comment: Привет, ты хотел в телеге хотел пообщаться, я не против: https://t.me/VladStarik